# More Anti-bonding or less bonding electrons?

Tags: stability, molecules, ionization-energy, electron-affinity

Is a molecule **more stable** with *less bonding* electrons or *more anti-bonding* electrons? This question arose when I was asked the stability comparison between $\ce{N2^+}$ and $\ce{N2^-}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both (N2)+ and (N2)- have same bond order of 2.5 but (N2)+ would be more stable as it has lesser number of electrons leading to lower inter-electronic repulsions.It can also be said that (N2)- has more antibonding electrons leading to a lower stability than (N2)+

Comment: Elaborating a bit- intro texts often show bonding and anti bonding orbitals equidistant from the starting atomic orbitals, but when you do the math, bonding orbitals are stabilized by a smaller amount than antibonding orbitals are destabilized

Comment: @Andrew, Is that really true? I don't know much about this topic but I always thought that energy is partitioned equally such that the potential lost by BMO is same as that gained by ABMO.

Comment: Yes. The equal separation is a very useful approximation, but not quite quantititatively correct. The extra destabilization of the antibonding orbitals is why, for example, He2 is not as stable as He.